# How to make a horizontal pgfplots bar chart with logarithmic x-axis and and no whitespace between bars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

There is alas some (understatement) dissonance between my idea of a figure and the figure I am currently able to make using `tikz` and `pgfplots`. I want to make a figure that looks like this

[image]

however my poor knowledge of `tikz` and `pgfplots` only allowed me to come up with this (I apologize in advance) terrible MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xbar=0pt,
        enlargelimits=0.15,
        width=.9\textwidth,
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        ytick={0,...,3},
        yticklabels = {AA, BB, CC},
        ytick=data,
        every axis plot/.append style={fill},
        y = 0.4cm,
        xmode=log,log basis x=10,
        xbar stacked,
        axis on top
    ]
        \addplot coordinates {(3000, 0) (832, 1) (1E7, 2)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I went through the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) for the `pgfplots` package but could not find something similar to use as a starting point and quickly became intimidated.

Is there anyone who could guide a poor soul?

Comment: Your MWE is not terrible at all!

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging words, @Jasper Habicht.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diagram is probably easier to draw with Ti*k*Z, but in case you want to use `pgfplots`, this can maybe serve as a starting point (with inspiration from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371717/47927)):

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotstableread{
        Label Start  Stop
        1     600    60000 
        2     1      3000 
        3     1e5    1e7 
    }\datatable

    \pgfplotsset{
      every axis/.style={
        width=.9\textwidth,
        y=0.4cm,
        bar width=0.4cm,
        enlarge y limits=0.25,
        label style={font=\footnotesize},
        axis on top,
        xbar stacked,
        xmin=1, xmax=1e7,
        xmode=log, 
        ytick={1,...,3},
        yticklabels={CC, BB, AA},
        ytick style={draw=none},
        extra y ticks={1.5,2.5},
        extra y tick labels={},
        extra y tick style={grid=minor},
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        xlabel={FREQUENCY (Hz)},
        clip=false,
      },
      minimum/.style={forget plot, draw=none, fill=none},
    }

  \begin{axis}
    \draw [<->, thick] (axis cs:1,3.5) -- (axis cs:1e2,3.5) node [midway,above, font=\footnotesize] {XXX};
    \draw [<->, thick] (axis cs:1e3,3.5) -- (axis cs:1.5e4,3.5) node [midway,above, font=\footnotesize] {YYY};
    \draw [<->, thick] (axis cs:1e5,3.5) -- (axis cs:1e7,3.5) node [midway,above, font=\footnotesize] {ZZZ};
    \addplot [minimum] table [x=Start, y=Label] {\datatable};
    \addplot table [y=Label, x expr=\thisrowno{2}-\thisrowno{1}] {\datatable};
  \end{axis}
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, @Jasper Habicht. This pretty much solved everything and then some! I particularly liked how you implemented the data table.

Comment: I apologize for annoying you again but is there a way to change the color of the bars from blue to something else? Also, is it possible to change the color of the edges? I already changed the color of the grids (`grid style={black}`) and ticks (`every tick/.style={black}`).

Comment: Maybe have a look over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99320/47927

Comment: How foolish am I! Saw that one earlier but apparently misread something. Thank you again, @Jasper Habicht, and yet again I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: This site is exactly for asking questions. So, there is absolutely no reason to apologise!